The different choises of a metric with the next form: $ds^{2}=-Adt^2+Bdr^2+Cd\Omega^2$
In some papers the starting point is a metric with the next form:
$$ds^{2}=-A(t,r)^{2}dt^{2}+B(t,r)^{2}dr^{2}+r^{2}d\Omega^{2}.$$
Like in the Schwarzschild metric where they choice A=exp and B=exp something and then they calculate the tensors and put them in the einstein field equations.
But in a 1946 paper from Bondi and Tolman they start with the next metric:
$$ds^{2}=-dt^{2}+X^{2}(t,r)dr^{2}+Y^{2}(t,r)d\Omega^{2}$$
and then they get the lemaitre-tolman-bondi metric.
I want to know the differences of taking one of this choices. I am thinking about the reference system or the proper time chosen but Idk.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_frame
